# MapMaker().weakValues().makeMap() removes entry from map if key is unreachable

Tags: java, guava

Noticed that **`MapMaker().weakValues().makeMap()`** removes entry from map if key is unreachable.

Our requirement is that map entries should be only removed from map only when values are unreachable. Is that possible with guava's MapMaker?

Comment: "if key is unreachable" how did you come to that conclusion?  It should do what you want.

Comment: I want to create a cache of Map<String, Object>. String value will remain same, but everything it will be a new String. We don't want to remove the entry if the first String object is unreachable. If Noone is using the object, then only it should be removed from the map.

Comment: Yes, and how does `MapMaker.weakValues().makeMap()` fail to do that?